# C++ inheritance, members and redundant data

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two classes Foo and Bar with redundant members.  I want a third class FooBar that holds the members of both types which I can pass into functions expecting either type( probably with a cast) and not have two copies of everything floating around.

```
class Foo{
public:
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
};

class Bar{
    A a;
    B b;
    D d;
};

class FooBar{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    D d; 
};
```

In c++, is there anyway to do this without modifying code that uses A or B (or at most changing the types that code expects)  and without making extraneous copies or retaining redundant data? Simple Inheritance keeps around duplicate data. Having a common base class and virtual inheritance  compiles under clang but appears not to work.

Comment: What about using a union?

Comment: If you want to pass `FooBar` to functions that expect `Foo` or `Bar`, you're going to need to use inheritance.

Comment: I think the design is flawed. Classes should model behavior and not just data.

Comment: @Pradhan: a union would break things here.

Comment: @Cornstalks Ah, I misread the question and didn't realise he wanted a set-theoretic union of `Foo` and `Bar` :)

Comment: "appears not to work". If only there was a resource on the electric world-wide computer network where you could show broken code and get advice on how to fix it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question completely, but I interpret it as "Foo and Bar should share some implementation, namely the data members". Wouldn't it be sufficient to have Foo and Bar hold a pointer your FooBar class? Or maybe a Flywight? I still think it is a design issue, so if you could give more detail on what you want to do, somebody may come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler has no way of knowing that `Foo::a` and `Bar::a` refer to the same thing. That may be logically true in your program, but that's certainly not enforced anywhere in code.

If they really mean the same thing, you might want to have a common base:

```
class AB {
public:
    A a;
    B b;
};
```

And use virtual inheritance everywhere else:

```
class Foo : public virtual AB {
public:
    C c;
};

class Bar : public virtual AB {
public:
    D d;
};

class FooBar : public Foo, public Bar {

};
```

This way, there's only one `FooBar::a`.